# Is there a way to list all the GCP services and related APIs using a python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I need to get list of all the GCP services and related APIs using Python script. And whenever I run this script I should get all the current GCP services.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no API that provides everything. This API will provide almost everything:

https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis

[Discovery Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/discovery-engine/docs/reference/rest)

For the APIs that are not included, sometimes you must get permission from Google first to use the API.