# How can I list of all GCP services

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I use below script for AWS, need pretty similar one for GCP.

```
> import boto3

# Create a new session
session = boto3.Session()

# Get a list of available services
available_services = session.get_available_services()


# Write the list to a file
with open('aws_services.txt', 'w') as f:
    for service in sorted(available_services):
        f.write(service + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [reference](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/start.md#building-and-calling-a-service) for sample codes to build and call service objects in a GCP Project and this [reference](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) for using Google API Client.

As per your question, there is an answer provided by [John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75868634/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-the-gcp-services-and-related-apis-using-a-python-code) on a previous post, there is no API that provides everything, but there is an API that can provide almost everything

https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis